# jQuery maintain fullscreen mode on ajax request with the URL change

Tags: ajax, jquery, fullscreen

I have my project developed in ajax with HTML5 URL history to change / update.
Have any suggestions keepin fullsceen mode also on page change? when loading new pages the browser exits fullscreen mode.
I need to avoid updating the URL and only do when the user exits from fullscreen mode? Do you know what can be the problem? Any advice?